# Solidity，private function can't return value

Tags: ethereum, solidity

The code below can't estimate gasLimit by metamask， force send transaction failed also.

```
function calc(uint256 _boughtTokenAmount) private returns (uint256) {
    /* uint256 _circle = safeSub(now, startTime) % circleSecs; */
    uint256 _circle = 2;
    if(_circle == 0){
        return _boughtTokenAmount;
    }else{
        uint256 _d = safeMul(100 , safeSub(lastCircle, 1));
        uint256 _n = safeSub(_d, safeMul(safeSub(_circle, 1), safeSub(attenuationCoefficient0 ,attenuationCoefficient)));

        uint256 _ret = safeMul(_boughtTokenAmount, _n);
        testRet = _ret;

        _ret = _ret/_d;
        testRet1 = _ret;
        return uint(_ret);
    }
}
```

If change the last line 'return uint(_ret)' to 'return _boughtTokenAmount',this code works, and  variable '_d', '_n', 'testRet1' got expected value.

So my question is, how the return the variable '_ret'.
Thanks.

Comment: You can't call a `private` function directly in a transaction, so I assume you're calling some other function, which is in turn calling this one? If so, please share the code for the calling function.

Comment: function() payable public {
        processContribution();}


And the 'calc' function is calling in processContribution function.

Comment: Please share the code for the `calc` function. And for both, please just edit your question to include them. (Code in comments is hard to read.)